# Makefile append wildcard match twice

Tags: makefile

I have input files like `somename.in othername.in yetanothername.in` and want them in a separate folder as output: `somename/somename.out othername/othername.out yetanothername/yetanothername.out`

How can this be done with a Makefile? This does not work, because the wildcard can only be appended once.

```
IN = somename.in othername.in yetanothername.in
OUT = $(IN:%.in=%/%.out)

all:
        @echo '${OUT}'
```

gives this output:
somename/%.out othername/%.out yetanothername/%.out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something of a dirty hack, but this works:

```
IN = somename.in othername.in yetanothername.in
OUT = $(foreach file, $(IN:%.in=%), $(file)/$(file).out)

all:
        @echo '${OUT}'
```

I'm not sure if this is GNU make-specific.

Comment: Definitely GNU make specific.  Which is fine.  Just FYI :)

Answer (score 0):

```
OUT := $(foreach b, $(basename $(IN)), $b/$b.out)
```